# Django Admin for Multiple Django applications

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have been developing a Django project with multiple applications using multiple databases. What I need is a different admin site for each app. For example, myapp should use an admin site that just belong to itself. In other words, I need something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp_admin/ on the browser to access its relevant database on the admin site.

This is what I've done so far:

```
class MultiDBModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # A handy constant for the name of the alternate database.
    using = 'db_myapp'

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Tell Django to save objects to the 'other' database.
        obj.save(using=self.using)

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        # Tell Django to delete objects from the 'other' database
        obj.delete(using=self.using)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Tell Django to look for objects on the 'other' database.
        return super().get_queryset(request).using(self.using)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ForeignKey widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ManyToMany widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, using=self.using, **kwargs)
```

In the admin.py file, I have this:

```
mammothholdingsadminsite = admin.AdminSite('mammothholdingsadminsite')
mammothholdingsadminsite.register(User, MultiDBModelAdmin)
```

In the urls.py file, I have this:

```
from django.urls import path, include  
from django.contrib import admin, auth  

from myapp.admin import myappadminsite

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    path('myapp_admin/', include('myappadminsite.urls')),
]
```

But I am ending up with the following error:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mammothholdingsadminsite'
```

Please note that I have different databases (including db_myapp) successfully setup in the setup.py file.

```
.......
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },

    'db_myapp': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'testdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'myhost', #that is my amazon end point that I removed for now
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.dbRouter.MyAppDbRouter',]
.......
.......
```

I would be glad if I could get some help with having different admin sites for each app on a django platform.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `include('myappadminsite.urls')` with `myappadminsite.urls`, so the line in `urls.py` should read:

```py
path('myapp_admin/', myappadminsite.urls),
```

and here

```py
mammothholdingsadminsite = admin.AdminSite('mammothholdingsadminsite')
```

I think you need to do it like this

```py
mammothholdingsadminsite = admin.AdminSite(name='mammothholdingsadminsite')
```